# convert minutes to DD:HH:MM (not a date)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have tried different functions I found in SO but none give me a precise output.
I did one variant of this (adding days and changing to d:h:m)

```
const convertMinsToHrsMins = (mins) => {
  let h = Math.floor(mins / 60);
  let m = mins % 60;
  h = h < 10 ? '0' + h : h;
  m = m < 10 ? '0' + m : m;
  return `${h}:${m}`;
}
```

my last attempt:

```
  // Convert Minutes to Days Hours Minutes
  const convertMinutes = (totalMinutes) => {
    let Days = Math.floor((totalMinutes / 1440) % 60)
    let Hours = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 60)
    let Minutes = Math.round(totalMinutes % 60)
    let ret = ''
    if (Days > 0) {
      ret += '' + Days + 'd ' + (Hours < 10 ? '0' : '')
    }
    ret += '' + Hours + 'h ' + (Minutes < 10 ? '0' : '')
    ret += '' + Minutes + 'm'

    return ret
  }
```

totalMinutes receive a sum of different inputs(all in minutes!). I need this function to work as close as precise as possible. e.g.: `convertMinutes(totalminutes)`
`937d 23h 59m` `8d 00h 01m`

Comment: Are you able to use a library like `momentjs`. Makes your life a lot easier when dealing with dates.

Comment: Please include what questions you've looked at. A [quick search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+convert+minutes+to+days%2C+hours%2C+and+minutes) yields 152 results. It is hard to believe that an answer could not be found within those.

Comment: @codemonkey thank you, I’ll probably use this library in this project as it deals a lot with time.

Comment: @HereticMonkey as you probably know or not, it’s not normal to keep code or tabs opened that is not useful. And definitely I’m not going through my history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert 1 day, 1 hour and 1 minute into minutes; subtract one day from your input till you can't anymore; then subtract one hour from your input till you can't anymore; then subtract one minute from your input till you can't anymore or either return the rest. You have to respect that order. Here is a function that mets your necessity:

```
function converter(minutes)
    {
    dates=[1440,60,1]
    output=[0,0,0];
    for(x=0; x<3; x++)
        {
        while(minutes>=dates[x])
            {
            minutes-=dates[x]
            output[x]++
            }
        }
    return output[0]+"Days;"+output[1]+"Hours;"+output[2]+"Minutes."
    }
```

Comment: That's a very strange indentation style that makes it somewhat difficult to read. With JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion rules, it is generally not a good idea to have open curly brackets on the next line, for instance. Also, without the use of the `var`, `let`, or `const` keywords, all of your variables become global, which could cause problems down the road. Just some thoughts to ponder...

Comment: Thanks for the tips. What do you mean by having curly brackets on the next line?
Do you mean like this:
    for(x=0; x<3; x++)
        {
        }
Instead of this:
    for(x=0; x<3; x++){}

Why is that a problem?
By the way I think my code is not strange actually. I am a sort of boomer and I use identation to see what belongs to what no matter who long it may look. I am not into those symbols dynamic people use such as $:?.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. Needed to declare the variables with let and worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use division to get the days, then use modulo to get the remaining minutes which don't sum up to a full day. Use the remaining minutes and and do the same with hours (division and modulo).

```
const convertMinutes = (totalMinutes) => {
    const minutesInDay = 24 * 60;
    const minutesInHour = 60;
    let days = Math.floor(totalMinutes / minutesInDay);
    let remainingMinutes = totalMinutes % minutesInDay;
    let hours = Math.floor(remainingMinutes / minutesInHour);
    let minutes = remainingMinutes % minutesInHour;

    return `${days}d:${hours}h:${minutes}`;
}
```